# Site for Typography Question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask a question about a particular diacritical mark, specifically the name for one, but

- There's no SE site for typography,
- This mark isn't unique to just English nor am I referring to its usage but rather the **mark itself**, so the EL&U site won't do, and
- I'm not asking about how to input these characters either so the different computer-related sites like Stack Overflow, Super User, and so forth aren't applicable, either.

Is there one I should use? Or, if not, in which would you recommend I post?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, why not create a proposal on Area 51?

Comment: Because I imagine that if I proposed a site, I would be expected to spearhead it myself, and I neither have the time nor the resources to do such a thing.

Comment: @SarahofGaia nope, you can create it and then do nothing with it at all.

Comment: Oh really? That's awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @SarahofGaia in fact there already is a proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88060/typography

Comment: Oh? 

Well there we go, then! ^_^ Thanks for letting me know that!

Answer (score 13):

You can ask on [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

> This includes questions about:
>
> - Graphic arts theory and history; "Why" we do what we do and not necessarily the "how" in logo design, **fonts & typography**, visual
>     communication

Questions about **diacritical** marks are allowed on [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). There are currently 10 posts about this.

---

Here is the image you added in your comment:

[image]

It's called a [Diaeresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29) (also known as the trema or the umlaut).

---

Source [What topics can I ask about here?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Good suggestion, but I'm not asking the "how" either. I want to ask what the name of a particular diacritical mark is.

Comment: It's more the "what" than the "how", I suppose one could say.

Comment: Try asking there anyway. I don't think there is a more suitable site.

Comment: Should I post on their meta site first?

Comment: Sure: http://www.charbase.com/images/glyph/235. Also, it's multi-lingual.

Comment: @SarahofGaia It's called a **Diaeresis** (also known as the trema or the umlaut). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29

Comment: No, that's a common misconception. A diæresis (also spelled *diaeresis* or *dieresis*) and an umlaut are two distinct phonological events. A diæresis is placed over the 2nd vowel in a [dipthong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong) and signifies a syllable break; an umlaut is placed over the 1st vowel and signifies a pronunciation change. Thus, the character's name is context-dependent. See [here](http://www.newyorker.com/culture/culture-desk/the-curse-of-the-diaeresis).

Comment: I want to know what the name of the *mark itself* is, regardless of context. For example, the "." can be called either a full stop/period if used to terminate a sentence, or it can be called a decimal if used to separate the fractional digits from the integer digits of a numeral; yet it also has a context-independent name, i.e. a name for the *mark itself*, and that is a "baseline dot".

Comment: @SarahofGaia If you look at the history the  "2 dots" was originally called a "trema". The name change occurred when it was given to different meanings (with different names). So the name of the "2 dots" tcould be said to be a **Trema**.

Comment: Interesting. What source did you get this from? I've heard the word "tréma" (also spelled "trema") many times, and I've suspected it may be the word I'm looking for, but I haven't been able to find any information about its meaning.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com) might not also be a good choice. There are a few questions there about alphabets and diacritical marks.